# How can I export only the selected items in a list in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How can I export only the selected items in a list in react-admin?

[image]

We know that the [ExportButton](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#actions) can create a CSV file but only of the whole list (with the current filter and sort). It [can't be used](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3009#issuecomment-473911662) for the selected items in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied [this BulkDeleteButton](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/ed361d34f3d35634f53a0caf08bbd1467c18d8be/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/BulkDeleteButton.js) of the react-admin. I removed the undoable feature, the crudDeleteMany action and the red color styling from it. What I added is a combination of:

- the use of a provided exporter function
- a custom crudGetMany action with a callback that calls the provided exporter function with the returned data (payload)

The result is called `BulkExportButton`. It's the first component of the brand new repo [ra-extensions](https://github.com/christiaanwesterbeek/ra-extensions). I recommend you install it (`yarn add ra-extensions`) and you can start using it.

### Usage

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Datagrid, downloadCSV, List, TextField } from 'react-admin';
import { unparse as convertToCSV } from 'papaparse/papaparse.min';
import { BulkExportButton } from '../../../common/components';

const exporter = data => {
    const csv = convertToCSV({
        data,
        fields: ['id', 'b', 'c'],
    });
    downloadCSV(csv, 'somelist'); // download as 'somelist.csv` file
};

const BulkActionButtons = ({ resource, selectedIds }) => (
    <Fragment>
        <BulkExportButton
            resource={resource}
            selectedIds={selectedIds}
            exporter={exporter}
        />
    </Fragment>
);
BulkActionButtons.propTypes = {
    resource: PropTypes.string,
    selectedIds: PropTypes.array,
};

const SomeList = props => (
    <List
        {...props}
        bulkActionButtons={<BulkActionButtons />}
        exporter={exporter}
    >
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="b" />
            <TextField source="c" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);

export default SomeList;
```

Head to [ra-extensions](https://github.com/christiaanwesterbeek/ra-extensions) for feedback about the component and how to use it.